# PHP / SQL Select using LIKE clause

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have multiple strings that are like:

```
Non-Geographic Number 0843123456
Non-Geographic Number 0843654321
```

AND

```
Non-Geographic Number 0845123456
Non-Geographic Number 0845654321
```

In my `billing_voip_match` table, i have a description column with the following rows

```
Non-Geographic Number 0845
Non-Geographic Number 0843
```

And i am trying to get the above 4 values to match against the above 2 values but because there are no spaces in the numbers its not matching them at all.

The SQL Query i am trying to run is

```
SELECT * from voip_billing_match where description LIKE '%Non-Geographic Number 0843123456%'
```

which should return `Non-Geographic Number 0843`

and `SELECT * from vip_billing_match where description LIKE '%Non-Geographic Number 0845123456%'`

should return `Non-Geographic Number 0845`

Comment: It seems switched? trying to get Non-Geographic Number 0843 using %Non-Geographic Number 0843123456%?

Answer (score 0):

Your query should look like:

```
SELECT * from voip_billing_match 
where description LIKE CONCAT(SUBSTR('Non-Geographic Number 0843123456', 0, 26), '%')
```

The %-Sign is like an asterisk.

Comment: check my question. my strings have the full numbers and i need to match them with the ...0843 and ...0845

Answer (score 0):

You should trim the strings to the first x characters (in your case it would be 26 if I counted correctly):

```
$string = "Non-Geographic Number 0845654321";
$string = substr($string, 0, 26);
query = "SELECT * from voip_billing_match where description LIKE '$string'"
```

% means "any character" (before/in the middle/after), but what you're trying is to find anything with "Non-Geographic Number 0845654321" PLUS something else before or after (or just the string as is) so you won't get any result.

In my example you don't need % because you're already looking for the correct string (i.e.: "Non-Geographic Number 0845" )

If you want pure SQL:

```
SELECT * from voip_billing_match where description = SUBSTRING('Non-Geographic Number 0845654321', 0, 26)
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood it correctly you need prefix 'Non-Geographic Number' and just first four digits from string:

```
SELECT LEFT('description',26)
FROM voip_billing_match
WHERE description LIKE 'Non-Geographic Number%'
```

Answer (score 0):

You should do the inverse:

```
SELECT * from voip_billing_match 
where 'Non-Geographic Number 0843123456' LIKE CONCAT(description, '%');
```

That will return the row with the description of `Non-Geographic Number 0843`.
Do the same for your other three strings.

**Explanation:**

The pattern on the right side of LIKE must be completely found in the expression on the left side. Therefor the expression on the left side must include the pattern not otherwise.

[Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2ca307/1)

Answer (score 0):

Try this query, it seems to work.

```
SELECT  description
FROM    billing_voip_match
WHERE   ('Non-Geographic Number 0845654321' LIKE CONCAT('%', description, '%'));
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4328f/3)